# Import multilingual node in Drupal6

Tags: i18n-l10n, importing-exporting

Suppose I have 100 nodes in language of English, I am going to import another 100 nodes with different language but same content.

I want to ask is there any module can establish the relationship between two node(with different language), as a result I can change to another language of the existing node by clicking the language switch button?

Thanks

Comment: did you try the i18n and l10n modules? within that you could translate strings.

Answer (score 1):

Found a article at drupal.org and trying to implement it

http://drupal.org/node/907542